# Power bi dax calculate time intelligence

Tags: powerbi

I ve been trying to calculate previous month result but without success, last month to be specific. Any file I m trying to calculate the result is the same like it didnt use time filter.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fPAhnB2t2XWQKODOxKsEXRwD-_44Cm6r/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ry9C5zrcUi59CV6j3GqAYjngYlr3wIYg/view?usp=sharing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egIjk.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kedfq.png)

2 files , 1 contoso and my original. It should very easy but i m failing and the worst thing is i dont know why

Done Basicially everything. PARALLELPERIOD also doesnt behave like it suppose to. Slicer filtering is working fine, dax is the problem. I have check the program settings, updated desktop version, for the second screenshoot i have made timetable. Still nothing

Yield Mech. assembly =
VAR MechAssembly =
FILTER ( TJob, TJob[SekundærNavn] = "Mech. assembly" )
RETURN
ROUND(
DIVIDE (
SUMX ( MechAssembly, TJob[FirstPassQty] ),
SUMX ( MechAssembly, TJob[Antal] ) ),
4)

Yield Mech. assemblyprevmonth =
VAR MechAssembly =
FILTER ( TJob, TJob[SekundærNavn] = "Mech. assembly" )
RETURN
CALCULATE(ROUND(
DIVIDE (
SUMX ( MechAssembly, TJob[FirstPassQty] ),
SUMX ( MechAssembly, TJob[Antal] ) ),
4), PREVIOUSMONTH(TimeTable[Date]))

The first picture shows the first card, matrix formula + visual
last calendar month filter (like calculate suppose to look like). Second card + matrix calculate with previousmonth

Comment: What is the problem exactly. Please share screenshots, code and desired outcome.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18RpADDYIiNAgwDthegvzdfGMFgD034G2/view?usp=sharing the left result shows basic formula only with filter context last month filter visual mode, not dax. The right result is with previousmonth calculate filter, which is not working. Showing every result without any filtering. Code is available within the provided links

Comment: In order to use any time intelligence calculation, you need a well-formed date table.

Comment: Everything needs to be posted on StackOverflow for it to be useful to others facing the same problem. Paste your screenshots, data, code and desired outcome here.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have added to forms of the measure. Hope that coveres the essential information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this measure instead:

```
Prev. Yield Mech. assembly = 
DIVIDE ( 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM ( TJob[FirstPassQty] ),
        TJob[SekundærNavn] = "Mech. assembly",
        PREVIOUSMONTH(TimeTable[Date])
    ),
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM( TJob[Antal] ),
        TJob[SekundærNavn] = "Mech. assembly",
        PREVIOUSMONTH(TimeTable[Date])
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Peter! In terms of matrix the result looks very good and I'll use it for future growth date reference but in terms of displaying card result it return blank.                                 Below the formula that solves it every scenario

Comment: Yield Mech. assemblyprevmonth = 
VAR CurrentYearMonth =
    MAX ( 'Date'[Year Month Number] )
VAR MechAssembly =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        TJob,
        TJob[SekundærNavn] = "Mech. assembly",
        'Date'[Year Month Number] = CurrentYearMonth - 1,
        ALL ( 'Date' )
    )
RETURN
    ROUND (
        DIVIDE (
            SUMX ( MechAssembly, TJob[FirstPassQty] ),
            SUMX ( MechAssembly, TJob[Antal] )
        ),
        4
    )